# Android - Webview (kitkat and below): Error In Java Script Function 'includes'

Tags: javascript, android, webview, build.gradle

Trying to Call WebView , While Calling Local Web Page It will Gives Error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object ["Some Object"] has no method : 'includes',
>   source:   file:///storage/sdcard0/MyDemo/js/fileName.js

It will gives Error To Kitkat and Below. 
  It works Properly above Kitkat.

It was working Fine With gradle Settings below

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

and Dependancy

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1
```

Currently Using Gradle settings.

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true    
}

compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: please update your question where html code where you refer filename.js. It needs to be linked as file:///android_asset/js/filename.js

Comment: @Amod - If 'local' web page is called from android assets then we need to link as 'file:///android_asset/'. The above 'local' page is 'loaded from sdcard of device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `includes` method on string in your js file, which is supported in latest JavaScript Version **ECMAScript 6** and android kitkat webview doesn't support this version.

You need to make use of `indexOf` instead `includes`

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";

var n = str.includes("world");
# Replace above line of code and use indexOf. 

var n = str.indexOf("world") > -1;
```