# Django allauth facebook login failed to redirect back when in an in-app-browser

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, telegram, django-allauth

**Problem**

When in an in-app-browser, like Google Hangout, Telegram or LINE messenger, the user won't be redirected back to my website after a success login through facebook login dialog. It just shows a blank page.

Everything works fine when using iPhone Safari app or Android Chrome app.

**Environment**

I am using Django==1.11.3 and django-allauth==0.34.0 (which utilizes Facebook Graph API v2.5), and here are my settings.py

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends'],
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'zh_TW',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True
    }
}
```

---

Anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Cross check your integration mentioned here [Django-allauth Facebook Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001809/debugging-allauth-social-account-not-logging-user-in-despite-connecting-success/46049491#46049491)

Comment: Tried your settings but still no luck. The issue I am facing only occurs in the browser within a native mobile app (i.e. in-app-browser).

Comment: Is there any error logs? in logcat

Comment: check this answer if your logs are similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008921/android-webview-kitkat-and-below-error-in-java-script-function-includes/47009171#47009171)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2013, [Facebook: Native iOS and Android apps must not use their own web views for Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/26/october-2013-platform-changes/).

Technically, the root cause of the problem is that FB opens a new page to get correct login credentials, then close the new page and post the credential back to the parent page. However, there is no parent page in webview (only a single page), so it stays there as a blank page. see [Making facebook login work with an Android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648099/making-facebook-login-work-with-an-android-webview)